# What is overflow:scoll like on android?

Tags: android, html, css

I was thinking about using a lib for this type of scrolling but with iOS 5 it is no longer needed. Does overflow scroll work correctly in current versions of Android?

Thanks!

EDIT: css (in stylus)

```
#foot
    position absolute
    bottom 0
    height 40px

#main
    position absolute
    top 0px
    right 0px
    left 0px
    bottom 40px
    overflow scroll
```

Comment: I guess that depends on what you mean by correctly? If we know what you are expecting, then we can answer you more appropriately.

Comment: @Fuzzical Does it scroll? Does it not affect absolute positioning?

Comment: Yes. It scrolls. As to whether it affects positioning, it depends on how you write the code. The question is still a little vague (I'm not trying to be obtuse). The reason it is vague is because you can override nearly any behavior of Android quite easily and choose your implementation characteristics at a whim. How your siblings and parents interact can also affect the behavior of a given View as well. There's just not enough information to give a satisfactory answer. Tell us what you have, what you want and we can better give you the info you are looking for.

Comment: @Fuzzical Edited to show the css code I want to work. Will the footer stay positioned at the bottom while the overflow scrolls? Any gotchas?

Comment: Gotcha. Okay, now I know you are talking about CSS, not the normal Android Layout. That helps considerably. Thank you. Give me a bit to give you an adequate answer as I am wallowing through some code right now.

Comment: retagged your question so that others would know more quickly what areas you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Fancy,

Sorry about the delay. Setting up two new websites and got quite involved.

Android, itself, does not control WebLayout or CSS Rendering. The default Android Browser is not necessarily the default browser due to Android's licensing agreements. Ultimately, any manufacturer or user can install any browser they like to browse the World Wide Web. The web content rendering is based on this.

While many manufacturers do override and reimplement several aspects of Android, a majority of them leave the browser somewhat alone (I do mean somewhat). If you are not developing for a custom `Activity`, you are best developing for a real web browser. That is, it depends on which browser the user is utilizing to view their web content.

There is one hitch in all of this, however. The WebView widget in the Android SDK does, in fact, handle web content within a normal Android Activity. In this case, the WebView uses Webkit to do all of its rendering. Webkit is the same Open Source rendering engine that Safari and Opera use. So, those should give you a baseline if you are delivering your content directly to an `Activity`. Even amongst those two browser, though they use the same engine, there are some differences in how they render CSS. I'm not entirely positive which one the WebView favors, if any. In any case, if you know the issues for Webkit, then this will help resolve CSS issues that you might have with the WebView, if this is how you are delivering content.

FuzzicalLogic